# C++ Programing with Visual Studio Code - "exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am a novice programmer who wants to make some contributions to a C++ repository on Github.
Given that please be patient with if I am missing the obvious. I've tried searching for the answer and poked at the problem for serval hours but am simply stuck.

When I try to run the SolveSpace.h file the complier gives an error:
[Running] cd "c:\Users[directory location]\git\SolveSpace\src" && g++ solvespace.h -o solvespace && "c:\Users[directory location]\git\SolveSpace\src"solvespace
This version of c:\Users[directory location]\git\SolveSpace\src\solvespace.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

The executable from the repository's site comes as a windows portable file which runs just fine on my computer. The repository I forked is the source code.

Currently I have MiniGW installed as the complier.
I have the following plug-ins installed for VSC:

- Better C++ Syntax
- C/C++
- C/C++ Compile Run
- CMake
- CMake Tools
- Code Runner

This is the repository I am trying to compile without any modifications: https://github.com/solvespace/solvespace

Thank you

Comment: to build solvespace exe you have to follow the instruction available here https://github.com/solvespace/solvespace#building-on-windows not just compile one header file

Comment: crap, thanks for pointing that out - Ill dig into those instructions.

Comment: Look at your output `g++ solvespace.h -o solvespace`. That indicates (as Erwan said) that the only file you are compiling is one header file. VSCode is not easy to setup  especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: I would advise that you get Visual Studio C++ (community edition) much easier (and better) than Visual Studio Code.